# Display javascript output in plain text instead of in a textbox

Tags: javascript

[SOLVED] i've tried to display the total of two numbers below result  but i cant . please help me i'm new to javascript . i'm still learning. By The Way i'm new to stackoverflow ,so,i cant able to post image .It's really useful if you help me

i tried this

```
 function append()
{
 var num1=Number(document.adding.num1.value);
 var num2=Number(document.adding.num2.value);
 var num3=num1+num2;
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num3;
}
```

image link : https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B7s0BYiHsMBtNEx5cVFmRzZHVDQ

Comment: Image link is protected apparently...

Comment: @Mathletics  i tried to displaying total value of two textboxes under result text.. i tried this code document.getElementById("result").innerHTML

Comment: @Lukas https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B7s0BYiHsMBtNEx5cVFmRzZHVDQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a div tag and isert your result into it next to the text "result"

Comment: thanks i got it..
function append()
{
 var num1=Number(document.adding.num1.value);
 var num2=Number(document.adding.num2.value);
 var num3=num1+num2;
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num3;
}
In HTML

<p>Result : </p>
<div id="result"></div>